# Build.gradle: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'

Tags: android, android-studio, build, build.gradle, interface-builder

Help :( ! I have a problem ...

No signature of method: build_1wnbu4w853kkkkiptj1syh84k.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_1wnbu4w853kkkkiptj1syh84k$_run_closure1) values: [build_1wnbu4w853kkkkiptj1syh84k$_run_closure1@30e7bec0]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ulf.gostyle.qrcodescanner"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionmama "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Just a typo: versionmama

Comment: typo error: versionmama

Answer (score 0):

Should "versionmama" not be "versionName". It's likely failing because it doesn't recognise that.